# web api 2 image upload with parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I'm using web api to support the server side of a mobile app and I need to provide an endpoint that support uploading an image to a user profile.
What's the correct way to do this?

Basically the user json looks like this:

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "userId" : "guid",
    "userProfileImage" : "image goes here"?
}
```

I'm using azure blob storage an I am able to upload pictures to it (using multipart/form-data) but I have no idea how to pass the Guid for the userId along with the image to store the relationship in the database.